# Oneliner to compile multiple executables only with gcc

Tags: gcc

We can compile multiple source files with only one `main` function to the executable one:

```
$ gcc -o main main.c sub.c
```

If we have source files with multiple `main` functions, how possibly to compile multiple executables in oneliner simply by `gcc`?

```
$ gcc -o main main.c -o main2 main2.c # not working
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you cannot.  Why do you care whether it requires one gcc invocation or several?  This sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: I'd overestimated gcc's versatility. Thanks for the nope answer and the reminder of [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) .

Comment: Shall I post an answer just saying "no", or do you want to fill in more about the problem you're actually trying to solve?

Comment: I vote to close the question.